# Replace a string with each string in a list

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list like so:

```
List<string> _unWantedWords = new List<string> { "word1", "word2", "word3" };
```

And I have a string like so:

```
string input = "word1mdjw ksjcword2 d word3fjwu";
```

I would like to remove the unwanted words in the input string, but strings are immutable in C#, so I though I would do something fancy in one swoop with a lambda expression. Like this:

```
string output = _unWantedWords.Select(x => input.Replace(x, ""));
```

But I can't seem to get it to work, any ideas? :)

Daniel

Comment: If the list is long enough, consider using `StringBuilder.Replace` instead of `String.Replace`.  It doesn't through off garbage like string manipulation does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're subtle problems in *general case* with the task:

Shall we do it *recursively*?

```
 "woword1rd1ABC" -> "word1ABC" -> ABC
    |   |            |   |
    remove        remove again
```

What is the *order* of removing? If we want to remove `{"ab", "bac"}` what is the desired result for `"XabacY"` then?

```
 "XabacY" -> "XacY" // ab removed
          -> "XaY"  // bac removed
```

In the simplest case (remove words in order they appear in `_unWantedWords`, no *recursion*) you can put (let's use *Linq* since you've tried `Select`):

```
 input = _unWantedWords.Aggregate(input, (s, w) => s.Replace(w, ""));
```

we can't change `string` itself, but we can change *reference* (i.e. assign to `input`)

Comment: "input = _unWantedWords.Aggregate(input, (s, w) => s.Replace(w, ""));" did it for my case, as the words just needed to be removed in the order of which they appeared. Thanks for the response :) Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need?

```
List < string > _unWantedWords = new List < string > {
  "word1",
  "word2",
  "word3"
};
string input = "word1mdjw ksjcword2 d word3fjwu";

for (int i = 0; i < _unWantedWords.Count; i++) {
  input = input.Replace(_unWantedWords[i], "");
}
```

DotNet Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/zoY4t7

**Or** you can simply use `ForEach`, [read more over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-5.0)

```
 _unWantedWords.ForEach(x => {
    input = input.Replace(x, "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForEach` instead

```
_unWantedWords.ForEach(x => { input= input.Replace(x, "")});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ForEach function to replace the text in the input.

```
string output = input;
_unWantedWords.ForEach(x => output = output.Replace(x, ""));
```

You can create another variable as to not lose the original input.

Comment: This solution worked as well, thanks :) -Daniel